# How to acces object in nested arrays in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

Assuming the following a portfolio collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50e5a858ad06fe3439000001"),
    "name" : "Portfolio 1",
    "description" : "description Portfolio 1",
    "userId" : "",
    "wallets" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50e5a858ad06fe3439000002"),
    "name" : "Portfolio 2",
    "description" : "description Portfolio 2",
    "userId" : "",
    "wallets" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50e5ac69f214a46139000001"),
            "name" : "wallet name 2-1",
            "description" : "description du wallet",
        "cards" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe4b5906a1e830d000001"),
                "name" : "Card 2-1-1",
                "description" : "description card 1",
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe61f2c0f189310000001"),
                "name" : "Card 2-1-2",
                "description" : "description de la carte",
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe6202c0f189310000002"),
                "name" : "Card 2-1-2",
                "description" : "description de la carte",
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe6212c0f189310000003"),
                "name" : "Card 2-1-3",
                "description" : "description de la carte",
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe6212c0f189310000004"),
                "name" : "Card 2-1-4",
                "description" : "description de la carte",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe6b22c0f189310000005"),
        "name" : "wallet 2-2",
        "description" : "",
        "cards" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ec21063f3c5f9f12000001"),
                "name" : "Card 2-2-1",
                "description" : "",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe6ba2c0f189310000006"),
        "name" : "wallet 2-3",
        "description" : "",
        "cards" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ec21233f3c5f9f12000002"),
                "name" : "Card 2-3-1",
                "description" : "",
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I would like to access a specific card thanks to portfolio,wallet and card _id.
What I'd like to have is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("50e5a858ad06fe3439000002"),
"wallets" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50e5ac69f214a46139000001"),
        "cards" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("50ebe4b5906a1e830d000001"),
                "name" : "Card 2-1-1",
                "description" : "description card 1",
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

}

I'm working on mongodb 2.2.2 on nodejs/mongo-native-driver.

Any help will be appreciate (shell example or javascript appreciated)

Thanck you.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to slee's answer using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), though it's better to cull entries out of the results early to prevent unnecessary unwinding.

```
    var aggOps = [
        { $match: {
            _id: portfolioID
        }},
        {$unwind: '$wallets'},
        { $match: {
            'wallets._id': walletID
        }},
        {$unwind: '$wallets.cards'},
        { $match: {
            'wallets.cards._id': cardID
        }},
    ];

    collection.aggregate(aggOps, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: Yup, mjhm's right.  It's definitely better to put $match earlier in the pipeline to reduce the number of documents being operated upon later in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

> http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/

According to the mongodb documents this can be done by $elemMatch operator. I tried to come up with the query, can you check if it works for your case or you can modify according to your needs.

```
var projection = { _id: 1, wallets: { _id: 'walletId', $elemMatch: { cards._id: 'cardId'}}};

db.portfolio.find(    {_id: 'portfolio_id'},    projection )
```

Comment: $elemMatch works for projecting the correct wallet item, but it doesn't seem to work for the nested cards array.

Comment: Can you try: db.portfolio.find(    {_id: 'portfolio_id', "wallets._id"       : 'walletId'},    projection ). Not sure of exact syntax for the query.

Answer (score 1):

The [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) can be used.  Specifically, the [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#_S_unwind) operator is probably most useful in this case.  Bear in mind that $unwind won't expand empty arrays, so the first document in your example is excluded from the aggregation pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $unwind : "$wallets" },
    { $unwind : "$wallets.cards" },
    { $match: {
        "_id"               : ObjectId("50e5a858ad06fe3439000002"),
        "wallets._id"       : ObjectId("50e5ac69f214a46139000001"),
        "wallets.cards._id" : ObjectId("50ebe4b5906a1e830d000001")
    } }
)
```